# Algorithm for best-effort classification of vector

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification

Given four binary vectors which represent "classes":

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

What methods are available for classifying a vector of floating point values into one of these "classes"?

Basic rounding works in most cases:

```
round([0.8,0,0,0,0.3,0,0.1,0,0,0]) = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

But how can I handle some interference?

```
round([0.8,0,0,0,0.6,0,0.1,0,0,0]) != [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
```

This second case should be a better match for 1000000000, but instead, I have lost the solution entirely as there is no clear match.

I want to use MATLAB for this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the [SSD (sum of squared differences)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares) of your test vector with each "class" and use the one with the least SSD.

Here's some code: I added a `0` to the end of the test vector you provided since it was only 9 digits whereas the classes had 10.

```
CLASSES = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
           0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
           0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

TEST = [0.8,0,0,0,0.6,0,0.1,0,0,0];

% Find the difference between the TEST vector and each row in CLASSES
difference = bsxfun(@minus,CLASSES,TEST);
% Class differences
class_diff = sum(difference.^2,2);
% Store the row index of the vector with the minimum difference from TEST
[val CLASS_ID] = min(class_diff);
% Display
disp(CLASSES(CLASS_ID,:))
```

For illustrative purposes, `difference` looks like this:

```
 0.2    0   0   0   -0.6    0   -0.1    0   0   0
-0.8    0   0   0   -0.6    0   -0.1    0   0   1
-0.8    1   1   1    0.4    1    0.9    1   1   0
-0.8    1   0   0   -0.6    0   -0.1    0   0   0
```

And the distance of each class from TEST looks like this, `class_diff`:

```
 0.41
 2.01
 7.61
 2.01
```

And obviously, the first one is the best match since it has the least difference.

Comment: +1: Beat me to it! I was typing virtually the exact same example when your answer popped up.

Comment: Lol, thanks :) .. but I guess there aren't many other ways of doing it apart from using different metrics ..

Comment: Yeah, the only differences were using REPMAT instead of BSXFUN and ABS instead of squaring the difference.

Comment: Say, about `bsxfun` and `repmat`, what's the difference? I used to think `bsxfun` was more memory efficient (magically applied the operator along some dimension) unlike `repmat` but recent experiments have disproved that .. any comments?

Comment: @Jacob: I've never actually tested it myself for any situations, but Loren from The MathWorks has a blog post where she does some comparisons: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same thing as [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576129/algorithm-for-best-effort-classification-of-vector/1576159#1576159) did, only with *four* different distance measures:

- [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)
- [City-block distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)
- [Cosine distance](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CosineDistance.html)
- [Chebychev distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)

---

```
%%
CLASSES = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
           0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
           0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

TEST = [0.8,0,0,0,0.6,0,0.1,0,0,0];

%%
% sqrt( sum((x-y).^2) )
euclidean = sqrt( sum(bsxfun(@minus,CLASSES,TEST).^2, 2) );

% sum( |x-y| )
cityblock = sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,CLASSES,TEST)), 2);

% 1 - dot(x,y)/(sqrt(dot(x,x))*sqrt(dot(y,y)))
cosine = 1 - ( CLASSES*TEST' ./ (norm(TEST)*sqrt(sum(CLASSES.^2,2))) );

% max( |x-y| )
chebychev = max( abs(bsxfun(@minus,CLASSES,TEST)), [], 2 );

dist = [euclidean cityblock cosine chebychev];

%%
[minDist classIdx] = min(dist);
```

Pick the one you like :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple Euclidean distance algorithm should suffice. The class with the minimum distance to the point would be your candidate.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance